# SQL Adding count (from 2 tables) to existing select (of 3 tables)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, count

Doing a query on forum database. I am using this query to get thread name, poster, date etc.

(Left only thread_subject for now)

```
SELECT `thread_subject` FROM `fusion_posts` JOIN `fusion_threads`
ON fusion_posts.thread_id=fusion_threads.thread_id JOIN `fusion_users` ON 
fusion_posts.post_author=fusion_users.user_id 
GROUP BY fusion_posts.thread_id ORDER BY `post_id` DESC LIMIT 16
```

Basically, I also need to add something like the count below to the existing select, to count posts of each thread.

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS PostCount FROM fusion_posts,fusion_threads WHERE fusion_threads.thread_id = fusion_posts.thread_id group by fusion_threads.thread_id`

How could I do that?

Comment: `SELECT thread_subject,COUNT(*) FROM...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
SELECT `thread_subject`, COUNT(*) AS PostCount 
FROM `fusion_posts` JOIN `fusion_threads`
ON fusion_posts.thread_id=fusion_threads.thread_id JOIN `fusion_users` 
ON fusion_posts.post_author=fusion_users.user_id 
GROUP BY fusion_posts.thread_id, `thread_subject` 
ORDER BY `post_id` DESC 
LIMIT 16
```

Comment: Thank You ! :)

(Not enough symbols)